# Mongodb performance issue in 7.0 time series collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, time-series

we are finding slowness/inconsistency in write speed on mongodb 7.0
On 7.0.4 installation with 6.0 feature set and we are able to injest 250mn events an hour (batch size 100 events) with avg latency of 100microsecs per event. Once we switch to 7.0.4 feature set, the avg latency turns out to 500 microseconds per event and eventually increases more than 1000 microseconds. Sometimes it increases and decreases and shows inconsistency in write speed. After writing few milion events, if we switch again to 6.0 feature set, the write avg latency switch back to 100 microseconds per event and it stays consistent even after billions of events injestion. We observed the same with 6.0 installation too not just with 7.0.4 installation with 6.0 feature set.

Create collection query:

```
db.createCollection(“weather”,{timeseries:{timeField:“time”, metaField:“meta”,granularity:“hours”}})
```

we do insert many query

mongo is installed with 7.0.4 version
command used for switching feature set:

```
db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: “7.0”, confirm: true } )
db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: “6.0”, confirm: true } )
```

command used for checking feature set:

```
db.adminCommand( { getParameter: 1, featureCompatibilityVersion: 1 } )
```

Comment: I would suggest to open a ticket at https://jira.mongodb.org/ When I upgraded my MongoDB to version 6.0 I had a similar issue. Solution was to force the classic execution engine. When I upgraded to version 7.0 I got a significant improve in performance.

Comment: Hi @WernfriedDomscheit  Can you pls suggest how to force classic executing engine?  On 6.x the write speed is perfect.  Once we switch to 7.x, it degrates more than 6-7 times.

Comment: It was parameter `internalQueryForceClassicEngine`, but it does not exist anymore in MongoDB version 7. It was available only in version 6

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Our problem is, the ingestion speed is fine on v6.x and slow+inconsistent in v7.x

Comment: We have raised a JIRA ticket:  https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-85448  Will  be helpful if this is addressed.